# What's the difference (in this context) between a generic type and a type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types

Supposing I have a method:

```
void MyMethod<T>() { }
```

I can invoke this from another generic method:

```
void MyCallingMethod<T>()
{
   MyMethod<T>();
}
```

That's fine, but `T` is essentially a type here, all `MyMethod` cares about is knowing what `type` is represented by `T`, so why can't I pass a type like so:

```
void MyIllegalCallingMethod()
{
   MyMethod<typeof(string)>();
}
```

I'm aware this won't compile, but I'm wondering why the runtime would care whether it's a generic or a `type`, what am I missing here in my understanding?

Or, to phrase the question another way, what could possibly happen inside `MyMethod` that would make my suggestion break?

Comment: `typeof(string)` returns an instance of `System.Type`, which is an object not a type. You just use the type itself i.e. `MyMethod<string>();`

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - thanks mate, I know how to get this working, it's not real code. I'm asking conceptually though why a generic method/class can't accept a `type` instead.

Comment: Most important thing the C# compiler does is verifying that the code is safe and correct for any T that meets the constraints.  To do that it needs to know T, it can't do with an object that only has a value at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `typeof(string)` is evaluated at *runtime* and `T` is a compile-time constant, so the required constraint testing can be done at compile time.